# php ltrim() only remove whole words

Tags: php, trim

So I have this string `'/var/www/html/includes/default_includes.php'`
I want it to be just `'/var/www/html/'`

When using ltrim it turns into `'/var/www/htm'`, which I dont want it to.
I know its because ltrim removes single charters and not words, but how can I make only remove `'includes/default_includes.php'`

Oops forgot to say the string could aswell be `'/home/user1/includes/www/includes/default_includes.php'`, which then should turn into `'/home/user1/includes/www/'`

I have searched alot, but couldnt find an answer for this.

Comment: Understanding a bit more about what you are trying to achieve might yield alternative suggestions. I'll try to answer anyway.

Comment: I don't see how `ltrim` even gets you as far as `/var/www/htm`; it's simply the entirely wrong tool for the job. Sounds like a simple `substr` would do it though, with a negative *length* parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This very much depends upon what you are trying to do.

```
<?php
$sString = '/var/www/html/includes/default_includes.php';
// I could guess where you are getting this from, but that would be daft

$aParts = explode('/', $sString);

$aParts = array_diff($aParts, array('includes', 'default_includes.php'));

$sString = implode('/', $aParts);
```

Or, as I think you are simply trying to get the root directory

```
<?php
$sString = '/var/www/html/includes/default_includes.php';
// I could guess where you are getting this from, but that would be daft

$aParts = explode('/', $sString);

$aParts = array_slice($aParts, 0, -2);

$sString = implode('/', $aParts);
```

Comment: The second one was what I was searching for. Thanks

Comment: Good, the second one is a little bit more dynamic.